# Foundation error when adding custom data attribute for validation

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

The following script works fine however foundation returns an error:

```
$("[data-checkbox]").on('click', function(){

    $("#payWithNewCard input").removeAttr('required');
    $("#payWithNewCard .columns").removeClass('form-group');
    $('.yourPayment .sel-box').removeData('abide-validator');

});

$('#paymentMethodNewCard').on('click', function(){
    $('.yourPayment .sel-box').data('abide-validator', 'checkexpiry');
    $("#payWithNewCard input").prop('required', true);
    $(".logged-in-saved-card").addClass('form-group');
});
```

The error comes from this line:

```
$('.yourPayment .sel-box').attr('data-abide-validator', 'checkexpiry');
```

and it says:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

I need to toggle that data attribute as on some occasions I only need to validate some parts of the form and not everything.

The removeAttr works fine but not when adding it.

```
        <div class="small-4 columns expiryDateWrapper">
            <label>{{ 'EXPIRYDATE'|trans }} *</label>
            <select class="sel-box month" name="ccExpirationMonth" data-abide-validator="checkExpiry">
                <option value="">MM</option>
                {% for month in 1..12 %}
                    <option value="{{ "%02d"|format(month) }}">{{ "%02d"|format(month) }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <select class="sel-box year" name="ccExpirationYear" data-abide-validator="checkExpiry">
                <option value="">YYYY</option>
                {% set thisYear = date()|date("Y") %}
                {% for year in thisYear..thisYear+Booking.CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRES_YEARS_AHEAD %}
                    <option value="{{ year }}">{{ year }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: It looks good.. what's your html?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the selector. Looking at the html there are no elements with the yourPayment class. If you are adding and removing from the same element you should use the same selector. "#payWithNewCard select"

If you use data attributes it makes it a little easier:

```
$("#payWithNewCard select").removeData('abide-validator');

$('#payWithNewCard select').data('abide-validator', 'checkexpiry');
```

This will remove and add attribute 'data-abide-validator' .

Sorry for all the edits - should be good now.

Comment: it adds it but it doesn't remove it any more, I have made sure the selectors are correct...

Comment: it just' doesn't remove it anymore but it doesn't throw the error anymore.

Comment: As far as I know the remove won't actually remove it from the mark up if you view the element but it won't exist any more so the only way to check it is to try and get it again using $('.yourPayment .sel-box').data('abide-validator');